# How to get youtube-style ads in adsense on website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I've seen some websites use a new style of ads from Adsense, they take the entire page and make you wait X seconds before being able to skip it.

I thought it's the page-level ads of Adsense, however the page-level ads are only for mobile, while I get these ads on my laptop. They look like this:

[image: ads]
Does anybody have any ideas what ads these are and how I can get them too?

Comment: Can you share the webpage that shows that kind of ads?

Comment: @marcanuy [This website](http://slither.io) Displays this ad once, after losing the game about 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious about them too, so digging a bit into [that website](http://slither.io/), the kind of ads they are using are possible by [Google IMA SDK for HTML5](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/), it

> allows developers to request and track VAST ads in a HTML5 video environment.

Here is the relevant *javascript* code of the website:

```
o.elem.onclick=function(){
    want_play||play_btn.disabled||(
    want_play=!0,play_btn_click_mtm=Date.now(),play_btn.setEnabled(!1),spinner_shown=nick.disabled=!0,ldmc.style.display="inline",
    play_count++,
    3<=play_count &&
    !is_mobile&&adsController &&
(shoa=!0,adsController.initialize(),adsController.requestAds("https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/136317422/slither-io-game-over&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&description_url=http%3A%2F%2Fslither.io&correlator=[timestamp]")))};
```

So it shows the advertisements after the player loses 3 times. They are using the sdk library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/outstream.js"></script>
```

and using an AdsController to display them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ocho = document.getElementById('ocho');
 var adsController = null;
 try {
  adsController = new google.outstream.AdsController(ocho, oalo, oadu);
 } catch (e) {

 }
 ocho.style.display = 'none';
 ocho.style.visibility = '';
</script>
```

That makes it possible to use overlay ads in desktop versions of a website using some html5 elements.

> You may want to associate your in-page HTML and Flash ad slots with
>   video or overlay ad slots. This relationship between associated ad
>   slots is referred to as the master/companion relationship. In addition
>   to being used for requesting video and overlay master ads, the IMA SDK
>   can be used to display companion HTML and Flash-in-Flash ads. These
>   ads are displayed within an HTML environment, alongside other Flash
>   content, or within a Flash website.